# Masking input unpacked array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to "mask" an input unpacked array given a specific signal. If that signal is 1, I want the input to be all zeroes instead of the given array.

```
module thing (
  input clk,
  input rst,
  input packedBits[`PB_SIZE]
);
// ...
endmodule

module top (
  input clk,
  input rst
);

  logic packedBits[`PB_SIZE];

  mod_i thing (
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    // I can manually put `PB_SIZE zeroes, but I want the compiler to do it for me
    .packedBits(rst ? {0,...,0} : packedBits)
  )
endmodule
```

Putting just `{0,0,0,0}` when `PB_SIZE is 4 works, but how could I do it in a more generic way?

Comment: it looks like questasim does not support SV standard in this case. Why unpacked at all? switch to packed to work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replication operator:

```
.packedBits(rst ? '{`PB_SIZE{0}} : packedBits)
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.11 *Array literals*.

Here is a complete example on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/TjyN).  It runs on Cadence and Synopsys, but there are errors on Mentor.  It seems Mentor does not support this syntax yet.

---

Simulators sometimes struggle with complex expressions connected to module ports.  It is usually a good idea to simplify the connection using a separate signal.

```
`define PB_SIZE 5

module thing (input packedBits [`PB_SIZE]);
    initial #1 $display("%m %p", packedBits);
endmodule

module tb;
    bit rst = 1;
    logic packedBits      [`PB_SIZE];
    logic packedBitsGated [`PB_SIZE] = rst ? '{`PB_SIZE{0}} : packedBits;

    thing mod_i (.packedBits(packedBitsGated));

    initial begin
        packedBits = '{`PB_SIZE{1}};
        #1 $display("%m %p", packedBits);
    end
endmodule
```

This works on all 3 simulators on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/8unJ).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `default` in an assignment patterns. Then there is no need to know its size.

```
.packedBits(rst ? '{default:0} : packedBits)
```

Comment: That's synthetizable by Vivado, but Questasim is raising an error: `# ** Error (suppressible): (vlog-13178) Illegal use of assignment pattern outside of an assignment-like context.`. Suppresing it raises `# ** Error (suppressible): (vlog-2998) Cannot mix packed and unpacked types in this operation.`. And suppresing that finally raises `# ** Error: Can't use named concatenation literals here.`